# VBA - Copy column range values to specific sheet, remove duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to copy a specific range on an active sheet, then add those values to an existing list on a different sheet within the same workbook.

After that is finished, I would like to remove any duplicates that have been added.

```
Sub CopyUnique()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet, FirstEmptyRow As Long, expCol As Long
    Set s1 = ActiveSheet
    Set s2 = Sheets("Products")
    Range("A:A").Cells.Name = "types"
    expCol = Range("types").Column
    FirstEmptyRow = Cells(Rows.Count, expCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    s1.Range("C4:C33").Copy s2.Range(FirstEmptyRow)
    s2.Range("Products").Column.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

I am rather new to VBA, and I may have been staring at this for too long, but I am not gaining any ground with the above code.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: So you explained what you are trying to do, but can you let us know what's not working? Are you receiving errors? Do you have an unexpected result?

Comment: I apologize! I’m actually getting no results from the code. Nothing showing up on the sheet at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this

```
Sub CopyUnique()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, FirstEmptyRow As Long, expCol As Long
    Set s1 = ActiveSheet
    With Sheets("Products")
        .Range("A:A").Name = "types"
        expCol = .Range("types").Column
        FirstEmptyRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, expCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        s1.Range("C4:C33").Copy .Cells(FirstEmptyRow, expCol)
        .Range("types").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    End With
End Sub
```

But from what I can see in your code, you could reduce it to:

```
Sub CopyUnique()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = ActiveSheet
    With Sheets("Products")
        s1.Range("C4:C33").Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(1)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        .Range("A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Name = "types"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked very well, thank you very much. It copied all my formatting/cell borders and is counting those factors when removing duplicates. But this gives me an excellent opportunity to do some problem solving. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. If you wanted to paste values only you can use ‘.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(30).Value = s1.Range("C4:C33").Value’ instead of ,s1.Range("C4:C33").Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)‘

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this function I have stowed away in my personal Macro workbook:

```
Function rngToUniqueArr(ByVal rng As Range) As Variant

    'Reference to [Microsoft Scripting Runtime] Required
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary, cel As Range
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        dict(cel.Value) = 1
    Next cel
    rngToUniqueArr = dict.Keys

End Function
```

> Notice: You will need to create a reference to the **Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library**

Which you would use in conjunction with your new sub:

```
Sub CopyUnique()

    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set s2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Products")

    Dim rngToCopy As Range, valArr() As Variant
    Set rngToCopy = s1.UsedRange.Columns("A")
    valArr = rngToUniqueArr(rngToCopy)

    ' A10 start is an example. You may start at any row by changing the below value
    Dim copyToRng As Range
    Set copyToRng = s2.Range("A10:A" & 10 + UBound(valArr))

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        copyToRng = .Transpose(valArr)
    End With

End Sub
```

Essentially, with this dictionary, you are creating unique "keys" and outputting the result of the dictionary to an array.

The reason you need to `transpose` this array is that it's one dimensional. A 1-D array in excel is a horizontal line, so we do this to make it vertical. You can also create a 2-D array to avoid using `Transpose`, but it's generally an easier task to do it this way.